# New user registration activation timeout?

Tags: users, login

Does the "Activate your account" link, in emails sent to new users, have an timeframe for expiration?  I've had a few of my users run into a "Invalid verification code" error when clicking on the link, after waiting a couple days. If I resend the email, and they click on it within a few hours there's no issue.

I've looked through the docs and posts here and don't see any reference to one.  If there is a default expiration, is this something I can override?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [verificationCodeDuration](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#verificationCodeDuration) config setting is what you're looking for.  Defaults to 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks Brad!  Must have had my eyes closed while I was looking. Heh.

Comment: @bradbell is there a way to show a custom page/error massage if the verification link has expired?